# Interchangeability of derivative and max operator

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Consider the function
\begin{align}
g(y) = \max_{x\in X} f(x,y)
\end{align}
where $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now consider taking the $n^{th}$ derivative of $g(y)$ with respect to $y$ (assuming that it exists). Can I always interchange the derivative and the max? That is,

\begin{align}
g^{(n)}(y) = \frac{d^{n}}{dy^{n}}\max_{x\in X} f(x,y)\stackrel{?}{=}\max_{x\in X} \frac{d^{n}}{dy^{n}}f(x,y)
\end{align}

If not, are there conditions under which this is allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for these to commute.  Try $n=1$,

$$\begin{align}f(x,y) = & ~ -(x-y)^2,\ X = [-1,1] 
\\[2ex]
g(y) = & ~ \max_{x \in X} f(x,y) = \cases{0 & \text{if }y \in X\\
                                        -(1-y)^2 & \text{if }y > 1\\
                                        -(-1-y)^2 & \text{if }y < -1}
\\[2ex] g'(y) = & ~\cases{0 & \text{if }y \in X\\
                  2(1-y) & \text{if }y > 1\\
                  2(-1-y) & \text{if }y < -1}
\\[2ex]
\max_{x \in X} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) = & ~ \max_{x \in X} 2(x-y) = 2 (1-y)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, Robert. Any idea if there are conditions under which this may hold?